# Issues with LibGDX and android studio

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just created my project using the libgdx setup and imported it into android studio but when I added a desktop run/debug configuation and try to run the project I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle: Executing tasks: [:core:assemble, :desktop:assemble]
Information:8/4/2016 10:53 PM - Compilation completed with 2 errors and 1 warning in 3s 871ms
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':core:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Warning:Gradle: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
D:\android projects\project\core\src\com\roaingstudios\project\project.java
Error:(8, 18) Gradle: error: '{' expected
```

I have not done anything to the files imported into android studio. The files are the ones generated by libgdx

```
package com.roaingstudios.project;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class project extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture img;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        img.dispose();
    }
}
```

What is causing the error and how can I go about fixing it?

link to build.gradle files: https://puu.sh/qr2Uf/448c47ff9c.txt

Comment: The problem is not in your code. Try posting the build.gradle file.

Comment: There was multiple build.gradle files but this was the first one build.gradle (project: project) - https://puu.sh/qr2Uf/448c47ff9c.txt